# json parser error while making ajax request?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

Folks i am getting "parsererror" exception while making ajax request to server.On my dev box
its working fine but at pruction getting this issue for some users(not reproducible at local box)

I did google and found one of the probable cause can be  data format mismatch . For example server is
sending jsonp format and client expecting json format or vice versa.But this is not the case with me
becoz its json at both cient and server side.

From serverside struts 2 converts java object(which contains list of map ) in to json string internally.so
I see no scope of error here.

So i suspect there is something in data .for example :=data like scott" but i coud not reproduce issue
even with this kind of data .Can you guys help me to identify what kind of data inside
json can cause this issue/ or it can be a different issue altogether?

```
 $.ajax({
      "url": myURL,
      "success": function (json) {

      },
      "dataType": "json",
      "cache": false,

      "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
        if (error == "parsererror") {
           alert("Getting Error");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: check response from myURL ? is it a valid json or not

Comment: we can only guess :( as its at production

Comment: load the url (myURL) on your browser and check

Comment: Have you verified the server component consuming the JSON is in sync with your local code? What is the webserver, version, etc?